# Getting error on React router dom navigation Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using react version *16.4.2* and react router dom *4.3.1*. I am getting this error while calling history.push method

> Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the
>   new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.

```
                   <tr
                      key={w._id}
                      onClick={() => {
                        this.setState(
                          {
                            updatingRowId: w._id
                          },
                          () => {
                            this.props.history.push("/serviceoperators/form");
                          }
                        );
                      }}
                      className="cases-trow link-row"
                    >
```

this is how i am exporting my component

```
export default withAuthContext(withRouter(injectIntl(ServiceOperatorForm)));
```

this is what i am doing in my authContext component

```
import React from "react";

const AuthContext = React.createContext({ authorized: false });

export const withAuthContext = Component => {
  return props => (
    <AuthContext.Consumer>
      {value => <Component {...props} authContext={value} />}
    </AuthContext.Consumer>
  );
};

export default  AuthContext;
```

Comment: posting some code may help people answer you correctly

Comment: Please look the question again

Answer (score 0):

You have the pass in params `{pathname: "/serviceoperators/form"}` to the push function and wrap the component with withRouter.

Comment: I already doing wrapping component in withRouter and  it was working fine but suddenly showing this error.